# ngDisabled and ngClick can't work together

Tags: angularjs

I've this form:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <label for="GrpName"> Mail:</label>
                <input ng-model="customerToUpdate.mail" type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="loadCustomer()">
                      Load
                    </button>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="GrpName"> Username:</label>
                <input ng-disabled="{{isDisabled}}"  ng-model="customerToUpdate.username" type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
              </div>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.isDisabled = true;

$scope.loadCustomer = function() {

    Customer.getByEmail($scope.customerToUpdate.mail)
              .success(function(customer, status, headers, config) {

                    if(!isEmptyObject(customer)){
                        $scope.isDisabled = false;
                    }else
                    $scope.isDisabled = true;

        });
    };
```

Using chrome, i can inspect and see that `ng-disabled` changed to `true` and `false` but no UI updates. I also tried `readonly` instead but same result..

I'm missing something?

Comment: should be ng-disabled="isDisabled"

Comment: Solved, can u make an answer? i don't understand the difference.. And why  ng-disabled changed to true and false in the inspect mode but not changing in the UI ?

Comment: Just summing up: ng-disabled use '=' , so u must pass variable (not value) otherwise directive fails and do nothing, so it remains ng-disabled="..." (not disabled="...")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ng-disabled [is bound with '=' not with '@'](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled), so you should not use the braces:

Turn your

```
<input ng-disabled="{{isDisabled}}"  ng-model="customerToUpdate.username" type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
```

into

```
<input ng-disabled="isDisabled"  ng-model="customerToUpdate.username" type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
```

and it should work!

Comment: i've already solved it thank you, can you read my comment under the question ?

Answer (score -1):

after you make http request and in the callback after change $scope you must use 
$scope.$apply();
to force reflection in view